# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un usuario es inactivo durante un tiempo en PHP / Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual, como requisito, debería desloguear un usuario que ha estado inactivo por 1 hora, por ejemplo cuando deja el PC o bien cuando en esa pestaña no interactúa.

La cuestión es que ahora mismo tengo el código de PHP siguiente:

```
  // Checking the session
  if (!isset($_SESSION['created'])) {
    $_SESSION['created'] = time();
  } else if (time() - $_SESSION['created'] > 3600) {
      // session started more than 1 hour ago
      session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
      $_SESSION['created'] = time();  // update creation time
      logOut();
  }
```

Obviamente, este código "no funciona" correctamente. Porque retira la sesión del usuario 1h después de haberla iniciado (esté o no inactivo).

**¿Cómo puedo conseguir que mi código sepa que el usuario ha estado inactivo 1h para poder hacer logout?**

Gracias por todo.

Comment: estas haciendo uso de algún framework ? hay varios que te dan control sobre esto. Sino cada vez que tengas actividad del usuario, actualizas una variable en la sesión guardando la hora actual. Y puede saber cuanto hace que no ha estado activo el usuario.

Comment: No. No uso frameworks.

Comment: Aqui tienes un modo [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9049911/5675636]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La comprobación yo la haría desde el lado cliente. Puedes crear un script usando JQuery que detecte si el usuario ha movido el ratón o ha pulsado alguna tecla.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var contadorAfk = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Cada minuto se lanza la función ctrlTiempo
    var contadorAfk = setInterval(ctrlTiempo, 60000); 

    //Si el usuario mueve el ratón cambiamos la variable a 0.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        contadorAfk = 0;
    });
    //Si el usuario presiona alguna tecla cambiamos la variable a 0.
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        contadorAfk = 0;
    });
});

function ctrlTiempo() {
    //Se aumenta en 1 la variable.
    contadorAfk++;
    //Se comprueba si ha pasado del tiempo que designemos.
    if (contadorAfk > 59) { // Más de 59 minutos, lo detectamos como ausente o inactivo.
        //La función o código que necesites para cerrar la sesión del usuario.
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muy interesante. Podría redireccionar a la página que quisiera poniendo como dato logout=true y así poder hacer unset a la Session con PHP.

Gracias!

Comment: @ramonguardia Exactamente, una buena práctica sería hacer eso mediante [ajax antiguo](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), o con la version [ajax de jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), e incluso con la nueva función [fetch de js](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch), esas serían las tres opciones que yo te recomendaría, para no hacer una redirección directa, y que deba pasar algún tipo de filtro